# Can't import module qgis in Python 3.9.2

Tags: python, sql, qgis

I'm working on Python 3.9.2 and got this

> error :No module named qgis

I'm trying to connect to a database and query within it.
I've seen the code beLow working under python 2. Is there any difference with Python 3?

```
[...]
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils


uri.setConnection('{0}'.format(hote_IP), "5432", '{0}'.format(xxx), '{0}'.format(xxx),'{0}'.format(xxx))    
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")    
db.setHostName(uri.host())    
db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())    
db.setPort(int(uri.port()))    
db.setUserName(uri.username())    
db.setPassword(uri.password())

sql = '''select field1, field2 from schema.table'''    
query = db.exec_(sql)
print(str(query.value(0))
```

Comment: You have to install it afresh in your Python 3 environment.

Comment: How do I do this ?

Comment: Installing it seems to be a little complex. The instructions are here: https://guides.lib.utexas.edu/gis/python-qgis-scripting. According to those docs, it seems to install its own copy of Python 3.7. That may mean it does not yet support Python 3.9.

Comment: Then should I install Python 3.7. ? Can I choose which one to run since I'mma have two installed ?

Comment: It appears from the docs that if you install `qgis` it will install Python 3.7 anyway, itself. And you can have Python 3.7 and 3.9 on your computer at the same time without problems. I currently have 3.9, 3.8, 3.7 and 2.7, and I'll be installing 3.10 shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it again via python 3:

```
python3 -m pip install qgis
```

Comment: My pip is updated but it returns this :ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qgis (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for qgis

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem when creating virtual environments for python projects and then trying to import QGIS. It is quite complicated to install QGIS in a virtual environment. What I do to solve this is to create venvs that have access to the system level site packages where QGIS lives after install. I use the following:

`python3 -m venv myvenv --system-site-packages`

The prerequisite for this to work, however, is that you have properly install QGIS and can access that from your system level python interpreter. I use Ubuntu and the instructions properly installing QGIS on Ubuntu are [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu).